# SQL Multi line query in C# using SQLCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to load specific data from different tables in SQL Server using C# But i got an error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.  Incorrect syntax near 'EP'.  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.` The code run well as i have put a messageBox to show the query, a messageBox popsup and show full query but after that i have got an error as i have mentioned above 
Here is the Code

```
 private void FillGridView()
    {
        CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        { SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                ad.Fill(dt);
                gvShowAllData.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

Here is the Query

```
    string query = @"Select 'ACTIVE POSTING' as POSTING,e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.emp_fathername,e.emp_nic,e.emp_contact" +
",D.desig_id,D.desig_name" +
"from EMP_Master as e,EMP_Posting_Log as p,EMP_Designation AS D" +
"where e.emp_id=p.emp_id" +
"AND P.desg_id=D.desig_id" +
"and p.status='ACTIVE'" +
"AND E.emp_name LIKE '%" + tbSearchName.Text + "%'" +
"UNION" +
"Select 'INACTIVE POSTING' as POSTING,e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.emp_fathername,e.emp_nic,e.emp_contact" +
",NULL,NULL" +
"from EMP_Master as e" +
"WHERE E.emp_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT EP.emp_id FROM EMP_Posting_Log AS EP" +
"WHERE EP.status='INACTIVE')" +
"AND E.emp_name LIKE '%" + tbSearchName.Text + "%'" +
"UNION" +
"Select 'NOT POSTING' as POSTING,e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.emp_fathername,e.emp_nic,e.emp_contact" +
",NULL,NULL" +
"from EMP_Master as e" +
"WHERE E.emp_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT EP1.emp_id FROM EMP_Posting_Log AS EP1)" +
"AND E.emp_name LIKE '%" + tbSearchName.Text + "%'";
```

Comment: You have no spaces on the end of each line in your strings. They will be concatenated, but with no spaces commands will run together.

Comment: Try ysing a string builder, or string interpolation

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injection. Use parameters rather than string concatenation for all user input values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

although it appears 'in lines' in your code, you are just making one big line of SQL and your spaces are incorrect - you could try something like

```
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine(@"Select 'ACTIVE POSTING' as POSTING,e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.emp_fathername,e.emp_nic,e.emp_contact");
        sb.AppendLine(@",D.desig_id,D.desig_name");
        sb.AppendLine(@"from EMP_Master as e,EMP_Posting_Log as p,EMP_Designation AS D");
        sb.AppendLine(@"where e.emp_id=p.emp_id");
        sb.AppendLine(@"AND P.desg_id=D.desig_id");
        sb.AppendLine(@"and p.status='ACTIVE'");
        sb.AppendLine("AND E.emp_name LIKE '%" + tbSearchName.Text.Replace(@"'",@"''") + "%'");  //escape single quote to avoid SQL injection attack

        //....and so on with the rest of your lines

        string query = sb.ToString();

        //then as before
```

Comment: Thanks Man .. Love YOu :) Solved

Comment: I am not able to fetch image from database to pictureBox with the same query, would you like to help me with that? i have reload all the other controls data from Database but can't load the image with the above query

Comment: @kh - if you are trying to return an image - what methods are you using to get the image data into the pictureBox?

Comment: when i insert an image i first convert image into memory stream through buffer and store image as a raw format , and for reloading image from database to picturebox i convert image from memory stream and store the image in a byte[] array. Firstly it works well means image reloading to picture box but when i use the above SQL Query with UNIONS, it throws an error. Please help me bro

Answer (score 10):

You need spaces between your string parts. You are expecting the concatenation to create new lines but the reality is that is not how it works. If you want a new line or a space between strings you need to add that in the string.

The more important issue is that your query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You should always use parameters for user input.

```
string query = @"Select 'ACTIVE POSTING' as POSTING,e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.emp_fathername,e.emp_nic,e.emp_contact,D.desig_id,D.desig_name
 from EMP_Master as e,EMP_Posting_Log as p,EMP_Designation AS D
 where e.emp_id=p.emp_id
 AND P.desg_id=D.desig_id
 and p.status='ACTIVE'
 AND E.emp_name LIKE @tbSearchName
 UNION
 Select 'INACTIVE POSTING' as POSTING,e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.emp_fathername,e.emp_nic,e.emp_contact,NULL,NULL
 from EMP_Master as e
 WHERE E.emp_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT EP.emp_id FROM EMP_Posting_Log AS EP
 WHERE EP.status='INACTIVE')
 AND E.emp_name LIKE @tbSearchName
 UNION
 Select 'NOT POSTING' as POSTING,e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.emp_fathername,e.emp_nic,e.emp_contact,NULL,NULL
 from EMP_Master as e
 WHERE E.emp_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT EP1.emp_id FROM EMP_Posting_Log AS EP1)
 AND E.emp_name LIKE @tbSearchName";
```

as for adding a parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tbSearchName", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Value = "%" + tbSearchName.Text + "%"});
```

Comment: @BenW - one of my favorites :)

Comment: @Igor Thanks for valuable answer, I have added space but now i am getting only error that `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.`

Comment: @khaafi - then you did not copy what I have above. Copy the entire statement and use that verbatim. Then use the added parameter I supplied and add that after you create the SqlCommand instance. That should fix your problem.

Comment: but still getting the same error, i have put `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tbSearchName", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Value = "%" + tbSearchName.Text + "%"}); ` after `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);`

Comment: @khaafi - You can test in in SSMS by copying everything between quotes (`"`) and putting it in a new query window and at the top add `DECLARE @tbSearchName varchar(2000) = '%TEST VALUE HERE%'` and put your value in there. Then see if that runs. If that runs then you did not copy what I have above correctly into your code OR you did not re-compile your code after you made the change. If it does not run then see what line the error occurs on and report back and we can see what the issue is.

Comment: @khaafi - seeing that you accepted the answer below you probably did not copy the space that I had above at the beginning of each line item or maybe forgot the `@` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Bro i did that and also i added that `@` symbol but didn't work... Anyhow thanks for the help.. Stay Blessed @Igor

Comment: @igor in that other answer, he doesn't need the spaces because it uses the AppendLine method of a string builder, and the line break acts as a space would.  I find that a StringBuilder produces clean looking code when building SQL, as well as making viewing in debug clearer.  Maybe adding a parameter is just another step for him to understand here, that's why I elected to escape the ' char in his SQL string - if you know of a SQL injection attack that defeats that, I'd be interested to see it - I've never thought of/seen one though.

Answer (score 6):

Your problems are because of the concatenation of strings. You can write strings on multiple lines without using `+` when you start your string with `@`

```
string query = @"
Select 'ACTIVE POSTING' as POSTING, e.emp_id, e.emp_name, 
        e.emp_fathername, e.emp_nic, e.emp_contact, D.desig_id, D.desig_name

//and so on continue with your query
";
```

Also look into `SqlCommand.Parameters` to prevent your code from sql injection.